How do you define a generic KeyPath in SwiftUI?
I am using two different types with the same parameters. I want to minimize the code for these two types by using a single generic solution. How can I do this?
struct ContentView<T>: View {
    let myKey: KeyPath<T, CGFloat> = \T.size.height
    let myKey1: KeyPath<MyCustomType1, CGFloat> = \MyCustomType1.size.height
    let myKey2: KeyPath<MyCustomType2, CGFloat> = \MyCustomType2.size.height
    let value1: MyCustomType1 = MyCustomType1(label: "Circle", size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 200))
    let value2: MyCustomType2 = MyCustomType2(label: "Rectangle", size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 200))
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyView1(value: value1, myKey: myKey1)   
            MyView2(value: value2, myKey: myKey2)               
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct MyCustomType1 {
    var label: String
    var size: CGSize = .zero 
}


struct MyView1: View {
    let value: MyCustomType1
    let myKey: KeyPath<MyCustomType1, CGFloat> 
    var body: some View {  
        let size: CGFloat = value[keyPath: myKey]  
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.black)
            .frame(width: size, height: size)           .overlay(Text(String(describing: size)).foregroundColor(.white))     
    }
}


struct MyCustomType2 {
    var label: String
    var size: CGSize = .zero
}


struct MyView2: View {
    let value: MyCustomType2
    let myKey: KeyPath<MyCustomType2, CGFloat> 
    var body: some View { 
        let size: CGFloat = value[keyPath: myKey]
         Rectangle()
             .fill(Color.black)
             .frame(width: size, height: size)             .overlay(Text(String(describing: size)).foregroundColor(.white))   
     }
 }



It's also very unclear what the context is. Why do you have two similar types in the first place? Can you give a practical situation to motivate this design?

I do not have ">" in my code or my xcode, it is stackoverflow. I need to have generic one because they are almost same but they are not the same.

Well that's not true for the code you showed. In any case, have you considered using protocols? The similar parts can be requirements of a protocol, and the two types can both conform to the protocol and the generic code that you want to write will operate on a type parameter constrained to that protocol. I don't see the relevance of key paths here. Please edit to include a representative example of your actual situation.

What is wrong with the question about creating a generic solution based on the given working and representative example of my actual situation? you need another example? or the question about making generic is not clear?

You didn't explain the problem clearly. If I were to fix the current code in the question, I would just remove the duplication - have a single MyCustomType and a single MyView. The code will still produce the same output. The point is that the current code does not necessitate the use of two very similar types.

I have 2 types like in question and they have both size, that is why i need to make generic like example in question, I really cannot understand what is unclear for you?

Can you show the generic code that you want to write but doesn't compile? Perhaps I can guess what you are trying to do from there. Right now you just have let myKey: KeyPath<T, CGFloat> = \T.size.height which is not used anywhere so I don't know what you want to do with key.

For example in code I have KeyPath<MyCustomType1, CGFloat> and KeyPath<MyCustomType2, CGFloat> which both have var size: CGSize instade trying to use like KeyPath<T, CGFloat>.

What is wrong with just duplication what you did with T?
